# How to arrange numbers creating new columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

## Example dataset in pandas

Below is a dataset with 3 columns.

```
c1 c2 c3
1  2   0
3  4   0
5  6   1
7  8   1
```

Now I want to arrange above dataset in such a way that the numbers **[3,4] and [7,8]** should fall under the columns **c3 and c4**.

```
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1  2  3  4  0
5  6  7  8  1
```

**Code for the dataset,**

```
data = {'c1':[1,2,4,6], 'c2':[2,3,5,7], 'c3':[0,0,1,1]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

#### Excercise

Assume there are 1000 such rows with classes [0 or 1] for each row.
How do you arrange numbers in every 2 rows in columns c3 and c4?

```
df = {'c1':[1,2,4,6,15,143,114,104,80,\
            89,100,104,70,99,70,46], 'c2':[2,3,5,7,85,80,\
            89,100,104,70,123,43,32,90,123,87], 'c3':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

     c1   c2  c3
0     1    2   0
1     2    3   0
2     4    5   0
3     6    7   0
4    15   85   0
5   143  109   0
6   114   80   0
7   104   89   0
9    80  104   1
10   89   70   1
11  100  123   1
12  104   43   1
13   70   32   1
14   99   90   1
15   70  101   1
16   46  123   1
```

#### Excercise 2

Assign classes accordingly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
a = df[['c1','c2']].to_numpy().reshape(8, -1)

Expected output :-
        c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
         1   2   2   3  0
         4   5   6   7  0
        15  85 143  109 0
       114  80 104   89 0
       109 100  80  104 1
        89  70 100  123 1
       104  43 70   32  1
        99  90 70   101 1
```

### Excercise 3

Increasing columns

```
Expected output :-
        c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7   c8  c9
         1   2   2   3  4   5   6    7    0
         
        15  85 143  109 114  80 104  89   0
       
       109 100  80  104 89  70  100  123  1
        
       104  43 70   32  99  90   70  101  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select columns for processing in list, then convert to numpy array by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html) and then reshape by `(2, -1)` - here `-1` mean numpy calculate by data how many new 'columns' are created:

```
a = df[['c1','c2']].to_numpy().reshape(2, -1)
print (a)
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

Last pass to `DataFrame` constructor and add new column with `[0,1]`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a).assign(new=[0,1])
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  new
0  1  2  3  4    0
1  5  6  7  8    1
```

---

```
a = df[['c1','c2']].to_numpy().reshape(2, -1)
print (a)
[[  1   2   2   3   4   5   6   7  15  85 143 109 114  80 104  89 109 100]
 [ 80 104  89  70 100 123 104  43  70  32  99  90  70 101  46 123  45  87]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a).assign(new=[0,1])
print (df)
    0    1   2   3    4    5    6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15  \
0   1    2   2   3    4    5    6   7  15  85  143  109  114   80  104   89   
1  80  104  89  70  100  123  104  43  70  32   99   90   70  101   46  123   

    16   17  new  
0  109  100    0  
1   45   87    1
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
a = df[['c1','c2']].to_numpy().reshape(8, -1)
       
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df1['new'] = df['c3'].to_numpy().reshape(8, -1)[:, 0]
print (df1)
     0    1    2    3  new
0    1    2    2    3    0
1    4    5    6    7    0
2   15   85  143   80    0
3  114   89  104  100    0
4   80  104   89   70    1
5  100  123  104   43    1
6   70   32   99   90    1
7   70  123   46   87    1
```

Comment: suppose there are 10k such rows and what if I wanted to apply above method for every 2 rows.

Comment: Think like 0 and 1 are 2 classes and there are 10k samples given a class for each.

Comment: @AdityaNikhil - Is possible add more rows to sample?

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: Do you want me to add?

Comment: @AdityaNikhil - I think sample data, please add them if edited solution not working

Comment: Okey let me check!

Comment: Can u explain your code. What does the reshape (2, -1) does? Mainly what's with -1?

Comment: @AdityaNikhil -  It means any number here.

Comment: @AdityaNikhil - Please add them if edited solution not working

Comment: The solution is working but am still trying to understand how exactly it's working. Because now I have to implement this on a dataset with 10k rows(similar to above dataset).

Comment: @AdityaNikhil - Still not understand why is not possible add more sample data?

Comment: Okay give me a minute, I'll add them.

Comment: I just added them. Please check in the post, I just edited it.

Comment: Are you there? Please reply, if you're there.

Comment: @AdityaNikhil - OK, super, wiorking well for me.

Comment: How to assign in pd.dataframe?

Comment: @AdityaNikhil - For me working same way, answer was edited.

Comment: Once check the post, I've added another excercise, to which I want you to assign classes accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224405/discussion-between-aditya-nikhil-and-jezrael).